# AWS Kinesis client fails with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I am following the http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/learning-kinesis-module-one.html tutorial on Kinesis Streams.

I have created two packages, one with the Producer and one with the Consumer. I can correctly produce data and I can see from the metrics dashboard that the data is getting into the stream.

When I run my consumer, I am getting the following stack trace:

```
1246 [main] DEBUG com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.samples.stocktrades.processor.StockTradesProcessor  - Caught throwable while processing data.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/util/json/JSONObject
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.leases.impl.Lease.toString(Lease.java:229)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.leases.impl.LeaseManager.createLeaseIfNotExists(LeaseManager.java:281)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.ShardSyncer.syncShardLeases(ShardSyncer.java:127)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.ShardSyncer.checkAndCreateLeasesForNewShards(ShardSyncer.java:88)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.ShardSyncTask.call(ShardSyncTask.java:68)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.call(MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.java:49)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker.initialize(Worker.java:395)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.Worker.run(Worker.java:330)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.samples.stocktrades.processor.StockTradesProcessor.main(StockTradesProcessor.java:102)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONObject
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 11 more
```

Comment: This looks like a problem with your classpath. Do you have the jar containing `com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONObject`, and have you verified it's on your classpath? How are you launching your consumer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got the same problem .
Just change the version of aws-sdk to 1.10.x. I used 1.10.7
May be you are working with aws-sdk version 1.11.x

Answer (score 1):

Kinesis Client Library (KCL) not compatible with AWS Java SDK 1.11. You need to use 1.10.x.

This has been fixed in KCL 1.6.4. So, you can update KCL ( > 1.6.4) to work with SDK 1.11.x 
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client/pull/75